# Add, Delete, or Collapse Report Controls from VBA

Tags: ms-access

[image]

I have a report with 10 different trainings (the screenshot shows 6/10).  I want to reuse this report for multiple counties.  Different counties use different combinations of these 10 trainings.

When I set a column to visible = true, it leaves an ugly white pace.  Ex: If I remove Training3, Training4 doesn't shift to the left to take up the space.

I'm looking to either remove the controls that are not needed, or to have everything the controls created, having VBA add them.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your db structure is not normalized. Instead of a field for each training, should be a related table with a record for each training. Programmatically changing design of report is not simple nor practical.

Comment: Of course, normalizing would mean a CROSSTAB query in order to achieve this output. I can understand why you went this route. Suggest you live with the blank columns, especially if the header labels don't need to change.

Comment: Good point.  It would be more tables but at least it would be normalized.

Comment: I'm going to create multiple reports.  Then create a table for VBA code to reference so it knows which reports to use for which county.